# PHP redirect after form POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm making a download button on my website that opens a modal with a request for password and then if the password is right should take the user to the real download. This is my javascript:

```
function submit() {

    var postData = $("#passwd").serialize();
    //alert(postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.redcraft.it/submit.php",
        data: postData,
        success: function(redirect) {
            alert('Submitted')
        }/*,
        error: function() {
            alert('Failure');
        }*/
    });
}
```

and this is my php:

```
<?php
function redirect() {
    $data = $_POST["postData"];
    if($data == is_null()) {
        echo "Error";
    } else {
        echo "<script>window.open('http://www.google.com/" + $data + "', '_self')</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

I'm using echo with a js script in php to try different methods to redirect since `header()` doesn't work. I'm sure the php is correctly called because i've added a row to create a file when the function is called, and the file is correctly generated.

Please, i need your help and don't kill me if i've made some "noobie" errors.

**Edit:**

This is the html of the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-mediom">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Download mondo RedCraft</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Per scaricare il mondo della redcraft inserisci la password che trovi nel video di presentazione del download!</p>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="userid">Password:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input id="passwd" required="" name="passwordinput" type="input" class="form-control input-medium">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <button id="confirm" onClick="submit()" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Conferma</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What are u trying to do?
in case of success u cannot call php function from js

Comment: The point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request **without leaving the current page**. Since you want to leave the current page: Why are you using Ajax?

Comment: Firs of all because it has to redirect only if the password is correct, second because i've it's the only way i found, as i said i'm new to web developing.

Answer (score 0):

just add one div in your html

```
<div id="outputredirect"></div>
```

and add below line in your ajax success or replace with your alert

```
if(redirect == "Error"){
   alert(redirect);
} else {
   jQuery('#outputredirect').html(redirect);
}
```

Comment: Ok, in this way i'm able to redirect but the password value in the php is null

Comment: provide your html to get how u specify field name

Comment: just change your data like this  --- data: {"postData" : jQuery('passwd').val()},

Comment: you not use full html form in your dialog so .serialize is not work just input value direct and pass in ajax data

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code should redirect to the url returned by the php script :

```
function submit() {
    var postData = $("#passwd").serialize();
    //alert(postData);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.redcraft.it/submit.php",
        data: postData,
        success: function(redirect) {
            location.href(redirect);
        }/*,
        error: function() {
            alert('Failure');
        }*/
    });
}
```